# Quicker alternative to IF function for multiple variables? (excel 2010)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have the following information in a table

```
      C           D
   ----------- ----------- 
1 |  25%      |   1       |
   ----------- ----------- 
2 |  50%      |   2       |
   ----------- ----------- 
3 |  75%      |   3       |
   ----------- -----------
4 |  100%     |   4       |
   ----------- -----------
```

If a user inputs into a cell (A1) any of the values in column D, cell (B1) will display the number in column C.

I am using the following function to acheive this

=IF(A1=D1,C1,IF(A1=D2,C2,IF(A1=D3,C3,IF(A1=D4,C4))))

Is there a shorter way to do this using a different function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is [the `VLOOKUP` function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx).  First, you need to reverse columns C and D so that your "lookup" column is in C, and the values to return are in column D. Then, in cell B1, use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, C1:D4, 2)
```

Changing the value in cell A1 between 1 and 4 should return the proper percentage.  For example, if you place the above formula in cells B1 and B2, and fill in the constants for all other cells, you should see:

```
  |  A     B     C     D
  -----------------------
1 |  4   100     1    25
2 |  1    25     2    50
3 |              3    75
4 |              4   100
```

Comment: Ahh.. totally forgot about VLOOKUP! Such a powerful function I always overlook! Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to make the lookup table row references absolute - C$1:D$4 - or t'll break when you auto-fill the formula to cells below

Answer (score 0):

Keep what you had. Just use the formula below:

=INDEX(C1:D4,SMALL(D1:D4,A1),1)

Short, simple, and no need to change your format. Index is a vlookup/hlookup function (vlookup is automatic and index is the stick in a car). Small looks at a list and the 2nd parameter looks at which rank you put, i.e. "1","2","3", etc.